# How to handle onClick to many objects from the same array

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, onclick

I have some problem and am getting furios a little. I want to .map my Array of Objects. And make everyone of them clickable. After click I want the particular object to show only its Avatar:

```
const stations = [
  {
    name: 'first',
    avatar: './img/1.jpg'
  },
  {
    name: 'second',
    avatar: './img/2.jpg'
  },
  {
    name: 'third',
    avatar: './img/3.jpg'
  },
  {
    name: 'fourth',
    avatar: './img/4.jpg'
  },
  {
    name: 'fifth',
    avatar: './img/5.jpg'
  }
]
```

Right now. I can access the value I need from my Database Array. But! I have a problem with:

```
this.state = {
      clicked: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}
```

My objects do not have separate state. So when I want to create some action based on this.state (like hide and show) it always work on EVERY element.

I have code which works in some way. When I render the list and click on any button, action occurs for every of them:

```
class radiosList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick(station) {
    console.log(this)
    this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked })

  }
  render () {

     return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.stations.map((station, index) => (
            <div className='radio_list radio_list--component' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => this.handleClick(station.avatar)}>
              <div className='radio_list radio_list--component radio_list--component-station_name'>{station.name}</div>
            </div> 
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default radiosList
```

Edit: first answer helped with accessing values I need.

Comment: Have you try to change imgSrc? 
 {this.state.clicked ? <RadioControls imgSrc={station. avatar}/> : null }

Comment: Worked, but I have made some bad description = > now is correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can achieve what you want by adding an additional `clicked` state attribute to data. There could be a better way but his is how I have done it for my purposes so far.

```
class radiosList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick(index) {
    console.log(this)
    var data = [...this.state.data];
    data[index].clicked = !data[index].clicked;
    this.setState({data});

  }
  render () {
    var self = this;
     this.props.station.forEach(function(station) {
       self.state.data.push({name: station.name, avatar: station.avatar, clicked: false});
       self.setState({data: self.state.data});
     })
     return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.data.map((station, index) => (
            <div className='radio_list radio_list--component' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}>
              <div className='radio_list radio_list--component radio_list--component-station_name'>{station.name}</div>
            </div> 
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default radiosList
```

Comment: This does not makes sense for me. You want to render from data array, which is empty? Cause anything is going to add to DATA after the click,

Comment: how is the data array empty. the contents from prop station are copied to data as an array of objects with an additional parameter as clicked

Comment: But it is not working. I get 
" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"
Still trying to fix the problem

Comment: @Draer I just realised a small mistake I made in my code. Sorry for this error. In forEach loop I wrote this statement `{data: this.state.data}` instead it should be `{data: self.state.data}`. I have edited the code. You can check it.